# Looking for a compatible table pagination for jquery.columnfilters.js

Tags: jquery, filter, pagination

I'm using jquery.columnfilters.js and I'm looking for a compatible table pagination.

I have tried tablesorter & tablepager + jquery.columnfilters.js without success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally found one that is working with jquery.columnfilters.js
jquery.tablePager-1.1.js which is very very basic but work ok.

http://slashjquery.com/tablepager/index.html#examples

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('table#filterTable') .columnFilters({wildCard:'*',notCharacter:'?', excludeColumns:[7]}) .tablePager();
});
```

I guess other pager can work but I have not found the correct way to add to my existing code.